# What did you think? 你觉得呢 vs 你觉得啥

Tags: translation, difference, equivalent-phrase

What is the difference between the following translations?

1. 你觉得呢？
2. 你觉得啥？
3. 你觉得怎么样 ?

Do they all roughly mean the same thing? Which one is most appropriate for spoken, written, and texting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they don't mean the same thing.

你觉得呢？

This translates to "What do you think? (about the topic we just talked about)"

你觉得啥？

This does not sound natural. It can mean "What did you just say (about your opinion / feeling)?" but its not common usage.

你觉得怎么样?

This is almost the same as 你觉得呢？, but is slightly more polite. They are equally appropriate for spoken, written, and texting.

Or, in certain context, this can mean "Are you Ok? do you feel sick?".

Comment: I wouldn't say 你觉得怎么样 is semantically the same as 你觉得呢 - it doesn't have any implication of "about the topic we just talked about". 你觉得怎么样 is just asking for a qualitative judgement. E.g. 小王, 小李, and 小周 are deciding what to do at the weekend. 小王：我们周末去看球吧，你觉得怎么样小李？ 小李：我觉得挺好的，你觉得呢小周？小周：好啊，说定了！

Comment: I feel like they are interchangeable in your example:
小王：我们周末去看球吧，小李，你觉得呢？ 
小李：我觉得挺好的，你觉得怎么样小周？小周：好啊，说定了！

Comment: Yeah I guess that was a bad example.  I agree they're _functionally_ interchangeable in that specific situation, but still _semantically_ different. I'd translate “你觉得怎么样” as "What do you think [Xiao Li]?" and “你觉得呢” as "How about you [Xiao Zhou]?" Thinking of it another way, you could replace “你觉得呢，小周？” with “小周呢？”, but you couldn't replace “你觉得怎么样，小李？” with “小李呢？”.

Comment: wait, wait (without further context) 你觉得怎么样 = has two translations? 1) "how do you feel" and 2) "what do you think." Interesting.